# Laravel : Object of class App\Models\DeliveryList could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My models looks like this

```
public function deliveryList() {
    return $this->hasMany( DeliveryList::class, 'order_lists_id' );
}
```

in blade I am trying

$deliveryStatus = $order->deliveryList->last()->delivery_status_id;
and the `dd($deliveryStatus)` = 6 //This is what I want

but when try to do something like

```
@if($deliveryStatus != 6 && $order->order_state_id !=4)
    <td class="text-center">
        {!! $order->deliveryList->last()->deliveryStatus->delivery_status !!}
    </td>
@elseif($order->deliveryList->last() == 6 and $order->order_state_id == 2)
    <td class="text-center">
        <a href="{!! URL::route('delivery.create', 'order='.$order->id) !!}"
           class="btn btn-success btn-outline">{{ trans('interface.makeDeliveryRequest') }}
        </a>
    </td>
@elseif($order->deliveryList->last() == null and $order->order_state_id == 2)
    <td class="text-center">
        <a href="{!! URL::route('delivery.create', 'order='.$order->id) !!}"
           class="btn btn-success btn-outline">{{ trans('interface.makeDeliveryRequest') }}
        </a>
    </td>
@endif
```

got

> Object of class App\Models\DeliveryList could not be converted to int

If I make it `@if($deliveryStatus != null and $order->order_state_id !=4)` it works but I need to specify the id 6

**Update**
This is also part of the controller maybe I am mistaking somewhere here

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $dateFrom = $request->get('dateFrom');
    $dateTo = $request->get('dateTo');
    $status = $request->get('orderState');
    $platform = $request->get('platform');
    $dashQuery = $request->get('dashQuery');

    $orders = (new OrderList())
        ->where('order_state_id', '!=', null)
        ->where('address_id', '!=', null)
        ->where('user_id', '!=', null)
        ->whereHas('orderDetail', function ($query) {
            $query->where('supplier_id', Auth::guard('supplier')->user()->id);
            $query->where('order_lists_id', '!=', null);
            $query->where('product_id', '!=', null);
            $query->where('quantity', '!=', 0);
        })
        ->with('deliveryList')
        ->when($dateFrom, function ($query) use ($dateFrom) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $dateFrom);
        })
        ->when($dateTo, function ($query) use ($dateTo) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $dateTo);
        })
        ->when($status, function ($query) use ($status) {
            $query->where('order_state_id', $status)->get();
        })
        ->when($dashQuery, function ($query) use ($dashQuery) {
            switch ($dashQuery) {
                case 'all':
                    $query->whereIn('order_state_id', [1, 2])->get();
                    break;
                case 'today':
                    $query->whereIn('order_state_id', [1, 2])
                        ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
                    break;
                case 'twoDays':
                    $query->whereIn('order_state_id', [1, 2])
                        ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays(2))
                        ->whereDate('created_at', '<', Carbon::today())->get();
                    break;
                case 'threeDays':
                    $query->whereIn('order_state_id', [1, 2])
                        ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays(365))
                        ->whereDate('created_at', '<', Carbon::yesterday())->get();
                    break;
            }

        })
        ->when($platform, function ($query) use ($platform) {
            $query->where('platform', $platform)->get();
        })
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: try it like this `@if($deliveryStatus != 6 && $order->order_state_id !=4)` !

Comment: @Maraboc didn't work

Comment: does `dd($deliveryStatus)` returns `6`?

Comment: @ab_ab yes it's

Comment: what is the data type of `delivery_status_id`?

Comment: data type of `delivery_status_id` int(10)

Comment: Is the error definitely coming from this line?

Comment: Yes I am sure it's coming from here

Comment: Is there an `@else` to the statement?

Comment: Inside `@if($deliveryStatus != null)` put the `dd($deliveryStatus)` and check the results.

Comment: What's the result of `{{ dd(gettype($deliveryStatus)) }}`?

Comment: try using casting:  `$deliveryStatus = (int) $order->deliveryList->last()->delivery_status_id;`

Comment: @RossWilson updated my question see all the `if` `else`

Comment: `@elseif($order->deliveryList->last() == 6 and $order->order_state_id == 2)` this is wrong.

Comment: @fubar is this what casing the bug here.

Comment: Well you're comparing a `DeliveryList` instance to an integer, so that'd be my guess.

Comment: @fubar I updated my code and showed part of the controller

Comment: update the `elseif` like `@elseif($order->deliveryList->last()->delivery_status_id == 6 and $order->order_state_id == 2)`. Also in the second `elseif` if you want to check the `delivery_status_id`, update it like `@elseif($order->deliveryList->last()->delivery_status_id == null and $order->order_state_id == 2)`

Comment: @ab_ab same issue no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use

```
OrderList::with('deliveryList')->...
```

then you'll get a **Colection OrderList** and it has one attribute **relationship** ('deliveryList'), deliveryList may be null or a array. if it null you can't get delivery_status_id of.

```
$deliveryStatus = $order->deliveryList->last() ? $order->deliveryList->last()->delivery_status_id : 0/null
```

you dd($deliveryStatus) = 6  because it is first colection and it has deliveryList

Comment: thanks this line solved the half of the question `$deliveryStatus = $order->deliveryList->last() ? $order->deliveryList->last()->delivery_status_id : 0/null`